# Cast object to unknown type

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I would like to create a dynamic method that populates a dropdownlist with any object based on the parameters. Here's my code:

```
PopulateDropDownList(ddl, GetList(), typeof(MyClass));

public void PopulateDropDownList(DropDownList ddl, IEnumerable list, Type type)
{
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    foreach (var item in list)
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(((obj)item).Name, ((obj)item).ID.ToString()));
}
```

Basically, what I want to do is to cast `Name` and `ID` to a type but I'm getting an error when I compile.

Comment: @Sayse the type or namespace 'obj' could not be found

Comment: you must cast to `object`. not `obj`

Comment: [This looks like an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dynamic` keyword, assuming you are running .NET 4 or above

```
public void PopulateDropDownList(DropDownList ddl, IEnumerable list, Type type)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(((dynamic)item).Name, ((dynamic)item).ID.ToString()));
}
```

Or, (if) you can use generic version and pass accessors to get the key and value.

```
public void PopulateDropDownList<T>(DropDownList ddl, IEnumerable list, Func<T, string> key, Func<T, string> value)
{
    foreach (T item in list)
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(key(item), value(item));
}

PopulateDropDownList<MyClass>(ddl, GetList(), x => x.Name, x => x.ID.ToString());
```

Or, at least, you can use reflection, to get required properties.

Comment: I have applied the second solution as I'm running .NET 3.5.